# (Amazon Linux) MySQL stops working on EC2 reboot

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services

My MySQL on my Amazon Linux all-of-a-sudden stopped working, here is the output of my commands:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-16 log]$ sudo service mysqld start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

[ec2-user@ip-10-0-0-16 log]$ systemctl status mysqld.service
● mysqld.service - MySQL Server
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Tue 2018-12-11 03:44:10 UTC; 3s ago
  Docs: man:mysqld(8)
       http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
  Process: 5558 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

  Process: 5540 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mysqld.service

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Server.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: Unit mysqld.service entered failed state.

Dec 11 03:44:10 ip-10-0-0-16.ec2.internal systemd[1]: mysqld.service failed.
```

I don't understand, why would mysql all-of-a-sudden just stop working like that and enter a failed state?

I also made sure that /var/log/mysql exists, it's ownership is mysql:mysql, and that the CHMOD rights are 755.

Does anyone know why it would just stop working like that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-install MySQL.  You won't lose your databases, they will still be in tact and can be accessed by the same username/passwords as before:

This works for Amazon Linux:

```
$ sudo yum -y remove mysql-server
$ wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm 
$ sudo yum localinstall mysql57-community-release-el7-8.noarch.rpm 
$ sudo yum install mysql-community-server 
$ sudo service mysqld start
```